# How to set vhost in Expressjs without hard coding?

Tags: node.js, express, virtualhost

So i know this works:

```
app.use(express.vhost('sub.xyz.com', subdomainApp));
app.use(express.vhost('xyz.com', mainApp));
```

But when i try set the host part in express.vhost dynamically, it simply doesn't work. (I need to set it dynamically in order to avoid changing the hard coded domains while i move between production and development.)

I tried the code below and i dont know why this doesn't work:

```
app.use(function(req, res){ return express.vhost('xyz.'+req.host, subdomainApp); });
app.use(function(req, res){ return express.vhost(req.host, mainApp); });
```

So how do i pass 'request host' dynamically to express.vhost?

Comment: Most likely, the function you are passing to `app.use` isn't equivalent to the function that `express.vhost('sub.xyz.com', subdomainApp)` would return. for instance, yours doesn't have a `next` so requests may hang

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know exactly your implementation details, but what I suggest and I think it's the most common practice, is to set those configuration params in envrionment variables.

so you would have.

   `app.use(express.vhost('xyz' + process.env.APP_HOST, subdomainApp));`

so you can have different env vars in production / development environments.

to set env variables from command line use

```
export APP_HOST=wahtever
```

or append just before execute the node command

```
APP_HOST=whatever node server.js
```

or add them to your *.bash_profile* or equivalent for your OS

Answer (score 2):

I misread your question so my answer is about programmatically binding vhosts. I don't know if you can bind new vhosts on the fly as requests come in, it sounds like a bad idea. I would just use @alfonsodev 's technique to force one environment or the other.

if you have a set of known subdomains and particular middlewares you want to execute for those domains, you could bind them all like this:

```
$ # set env variable before invoking the script
$ APP_DEVPROD=dev node server.js

// Default to 'prod' if no env var set
var p = process.env.APP_DEVPROD || 'prod';
var myHost = (p === 'dev' ? 'localhost:8001' : 'xyz.com');

[
  ['admin.'+myHost, handlers.admin],
  ['demo.'+myHost, handlers.demo],
].forEach(setVhost);

function setVhost(pair){
  var hostname = pair[0];
  var appFn = pair[1];
  app.use(express.vhost(hostname, appFn));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `*` as a wildcard in the hostname:

```
app.use(express.vhost('sub.*', subdomainApp));
app.use(mainApp);
```

See http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/vhost.html.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I used @alfonsodev's approach. Although all the above methods work great.

Comment: But i am still not clear what i was doing wrong? 
@plato i tried using next() also.